# Upscaling images with cv2 dnn_superres is very slow

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying the following code in a colab notebook

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
path = "EDSR_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
sr.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

sr.setModel("edsr", 3)
image = cv2.imread('images/script_0_image_0_0.png')

result = sr.upsample(image, (1080, 1920))

cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", result)
```

I have attached the image for which I'm running this code. It is taking forever to run the code. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?[image]

Comment: It completed after 23min and produced a 7.3mb file

Comment: did you see GPU utilization? I'm not sure if OpenCV just runs on the CPU if it couldn't use the GPU, even if you ask for it. "preferred" (target) kinda makes me wonder. -- also check RAM and VRAM requirements. it may have run on the GPU, but not optimally. -- perhaps colab simply didn't give you 100% of the time on a GPU? I'm not sure what they can and can't do

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if that could contribute to the processing time, but just looking at the image it could be that you are passing incorrect parameters to `sr.upsample`

```py
result = sr.upsample(image, (1080, 1920))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems you may have misplaced width and height. Try this instead:

```py
result = sr.upsample(image, (1920, 1080))
```

And even better, per [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d11/classcv_1_1dnn__superres_1_1DnnSuperResImpl.html#a3d8bf9e39c75939ab8d2de8396201a89), you do not need this parameter at all:

```py
result = sr.upsample(image)
```

Also, try to run this locally on your pc and use utility like [nvtop](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop) to check if your GPU is working on this problem at all.
Otherwise Christoph is probably right about Google Colab just taking this long.

Regarding size of produced artifact, check what size you are actually getting

```py
result = sr.upsample(image)  
print(f'result width={result.rows} height={result.cols}')
```

Also check the scaling of the model.

```py
scale = sr.getScale()  
print(f'Model scaling = {scale}')
```

If model up-scales 4 times or more, this would definitely contribute to the processing time. Try with a smaller image, something that will **result** in 1920x1080